# indent each nth element by base px * nth

Tags: css, less

Lets say I have n divs.

```
<div class="indent">1</div>
<div class="indent">2</div>
<div class="indent">n</div>
```

I want to indent the first one 10px, the second one by 10px more and so on.. How can this be done with css3 (or less)?

```
.indent {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.indent :nth-of-type(2) {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.indent :nth-of-type(3) {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

I'd like to make the above code into a 1  or two liner..

Comment: You could use a [loop in LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) but that'd produce bloated CSS for N _great enough_…

Comment: Just a note: The white space between `.indent :nth-of-type(3) {` will make it look for children inside the `indent` div. Pseudo selectors must be placed together: `.indent:nth-of-type(3) {`

Comment: The easiest would be to make these elements children not siblings, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0ujbe572/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) out.

It describes how to make loops in Less.

For your problem, this should do the trick, assuming you know how many divs you have in the first place.

```
.loop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    .loop((@counter - 1));    // next iteration
    .indent :nth-of-type(@{counter}) {
        padding-left: unit((10 * @counter), px);
    }
} .loop(3);
```

Here, this code would generate 3 iterations. <strike>Please note that the iterations are generated from the amount of iterations you asked to 1. Here, you'll have what you asked but in reverse order.</strike>

Comment: >in reverse order. - Actually this loop generates things in the proper order (because next iteration is invoked before current iteration styles so styles are "printed out" when the loop unwinds).

Comment: Also `padding-left: unit((10 * @counter), px);` can be simplified to `padding-left: (@counter * 10px);`

Comment: @seven-phases-max, thx, i'm always struggling somehow when there are operations involved in less. As for the order, thx too, i didn't think enough about this.